# date time function of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working JavaScript date time function it is Woking fine for me. just doubt here is from where this function will pick data ?

from client machine or from server.

Answers with supporting links will be more helpful.

update : if it is taking time from client PC then what if client changes machines date time.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Google is your friend

Comment: All the js function will be executed in client PC

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript executes client side so it will pick date from client machine.

P.S: If you execute it on server (node js) it will take servers date.

Comment: So it is not recommended to use javascript data time because in case someone change date time of machine it can cause a problem..right?

Comment: Yes, if the date time on a machine is changed the datetime value will also change. Can u elaborate what you are trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Yes the date and time will change if system date and time is changed. You can always cross verify date and time on server.

Answer (score 1):

Dont need to get date on client side store server machine date and convert into utc format or if you retrive the date on client side convert it into normal format it shows right time

Comment: then if you dont want to use the client machine store time in string then retrive it as a string donot treat like a time

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in script:

```
var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```
    <div id="demo"></div>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =new Date();
    </script>
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question.